# Delete from multiple collections using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I want to search multiple collections and delete using the _id property.

i am receiving an array of _id from the user and i am trying to iterate over each element.

```
var express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();


router.delete("/", async (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body; // this is an array of _id from the user


   data.forEach((element) => {
    let models = [];
    models.push(mongoose.models.Furniture);
    models.push(mongoose.models.Clothing);
    models.map((model) => model.findByIdAndRemove(element));
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

when I run this I don't receive any errors.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB operation is an asynchronous operation. So to get the error or result you need to wait until response returns by the database.

```
var express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();


router.delete("/", async (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body; // this is an array of _id from the user


   data.forEach((element) => {
    let models = [];
    models.push(mongoose.models.Furniture);
    models.push(mongoose.models.Clothing);
    try {
      models.map(async (model) => { await model.findByIdAndRemove(element)});
    } catch (error) { console.log(error) }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
Note: this code is not tested locally but the problem I have solved here
```